# Haskell, ford fulkerson, finding augmenting path

Tags: haskell

I want to write program in haskell which will find the maximum flow in a flow network. However, I don't know Haskell well, so I don't know what is the best way to do it.

My biggest problem is finding augmenting path.

In Java I would create array of booleans `Visited` (to know which Node is visited) and residual graph `rGraph` and using DFS I would find augmenting paths (if there were some).

But in Haskell...

That's my definition of type Graph.

```
type Node = Char
type Edge = (Node ,Node, Int)
type Graph = ([Node], [Edge])
```

So graph with 5 nodes and 6 edges I can represent this way

```
 ['a','b','c','d','e'], [('a','b',7),('b','c',4),('a','d',8),('c','d',9),('e','b',11),('d','e',3)]
```

I can try to do it "java style", but I think there is a better way.

What is the best way to find augmenting path in graph in haskell?

Comment: Can you just use [Data.Graph.Inductive.Query.MaxFlow](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl-5.5.2.3/docs/Data-Graph-Inductive-Query-MaxFlow.html)?

Comment: @DanielWagner  unfortunately, no

Comment: ...can you elaborate on why not a little bit...?

Comment: One way to start—though it's not particularly Haskelly in style—is to just use something like `vector` and `ST` to write the imperative algorithm.

Comment: @DanielWagner  of course, university project, have to write this project using only Prelude, so I'm trying to understand best way to do it before starting to write

Comment: Maybe you could start with "java style" then see what you can do to Haskellize it.